# g++ command with custom compiled opencv library

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I'm compiling the code with custom compiled opencv library. So I can't use "pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv" to do the work.

library structure:

```
/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/include
/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/x64/vc14/lib
/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/x64/vc14/bin
```

g++ command I tried:

```
g++ test.cpp -I/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/include -L/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/x64/vc14/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_calib3dd -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_contribd -lopencv_core -lopencv_cored -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_features2dd -lopencv_flann -lopencv_flannd -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_gpud -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_highguid -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgprocd -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_legacyd -lopencv_ml -lopencv_mld -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_nonfreed -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_objdetectd -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_ocld -lopencv_photo -lopencv_photod -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_stitchingd -lopencv_superres -lopencv_superresd -lopencv_ts -lopencv_tsd -lopencv_video -lopencv_videod -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videostabd
```

but I got errors when I comiile:

```
undefined reference to \`cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
undefined reference to \`cv::VideoCapture::open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error info:

```
undefined reference to \`cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
undefined reference to \`cv::VideoCapture::open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

Notice, `std::__cxx11::basic_string` means `std::string` in C++ 11.

Maybe you should add the flag: `-std=c++11` after g++.

Try this :

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -I/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/include -L/c/Users/kmes40505/Desktop/programming/library/opencv/x64/vc14/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_calib3dd -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_contribd -lopencv_core -lopencv_cored -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_features2dd -lopencv_flann -lopencv_flannd -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_gpud -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_highguid -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgprocd -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_legacyd -lopencv_ml -lopencv_mld -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_nonfreed -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_objdetectd -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_ocld -lopencv_photo -lopencv_photod -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_stitchingd -lopencv_superres -lopencv_superresd -lopencv_ts -lopencv_tsd -lopencv_video -lopencv_videod -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videostabd
```

Comment: well the errors still exist as before. There are undefined reference errors that I didn't listed in this question since they're all similar btw

Comment: oh and it's using mingw's g++ on windows